# Using R for oauth with factual

Tags: r, oauth, rcurl

I am trying to replicate the following apigee oauth call in windows 7 in R. I have tried Roauth, (python) oauth-proxy with RCurl (probably the best way, but I cannot figure it out), and others. Here is the apigee call that works fine:

```
GET /places/geocode?geo=%7B%22%24point%22%3A%5B34.06021%2C-118.41828%5D%7D HTTP/1.1
Authorization:
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="myKey",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1372529150",
oauth_nonce="1274556232",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="someSignature"
Host: api.v3.factual.com
X-Target-URI: http://api.v3.factual.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

My needs are for an oauth connection that stays open so that I can call the API in R. Any help would be really appreciated, specifically with how the above fields read into the solutions. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies that I'm not getting your exact request to work, that method is now deprecated (http://developer.factual.com/api-docs/#Geocode).  The good news is that connecting to the new geotag API call looks much easier and doesn't require the OAuth back-and-forth (http://developer.factual.com/api-docs-v4/#Geotag).  Here's what your Apigee request would look like in V4:

```
require(httr)

## Factual credentials
consumerKey <- "" ## your API key from Factual

## geotag demo - V4 API
geotag <- GET(paste0('https://api.factual.com/geotag?latitude=34.06021&longitude=-118.41828&KEY=',consumerKey))
content(geotag)
```

I'm assuming, though, that connecting to the other endpoints for Factual is still an interesting question.  Just this morning I got this to work based on the answer to [Using the Yelp API with R, attempting to search business types using geo-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728318/using-the-yelp-api-with-r-attempting-to-search-business-types-using-geo-coordin).

I'm just showing the place categories here but have used this signature to connect to the read places as well.

```
require(httr)

## Factual credentials
consumerKey <- "" # your key
consumerSecret <- "" # your secret

## authorization
myapp <- oauth_app("Factual", key=consumerKey, secret=consumerSecret)
## R will ask to cache credentials between these lines
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp)

data <- GET('https://api.v3.factual.com/t/place-categories?limit=500',
sig)
content(data)
```