# Using the Yelp API with R, attempting to search business types using geo-coordinates

Tags: r, yelp

Trying to connect to the yelp API using R and library ROAuth.

Great python sample using the rauth module and geo-coordinates:

https://gist.github.com/phillipjohnson/8889618

and would like to do exactly that but in R and using a library like ROAuth.

I've been attempting to create handshakes, etc:

```
credentials <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                                consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                                oauthKey = token,
                                oauthSecret = token_secret,
                                authURL="http://api.yelp.com/v2")
credentials$handshake()
credentials$OAuthRequest(testURL, "GET")
```

But not getting past the handshake. Yelp uses OAuth 1.0 which ROAuth package supports. From other code I've seen it requires an 'oauth_consumer_key', 'oauth_nonce', 'oauth_signature_method', 'oauth_timestamp', 'oauth_token'. I would appreciate any tips from people who used R to query Yelp using geo-coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: Yelp API methods and responses for both the Search and Business API. If you use search API,I think it should be like this authURL="http://api.yelp.com/v2/search"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - contacted the author who recommended using httr instead of ROAuth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the author of ROAuth recommended using library(httr) and because of the lack of simple yelp examples in R using either libraries, I figured others may be looking for this too. This will return either 10 bars in the Chicago area by name, or 10 bars in San Francisco by geo-coordinates. Replace the x's with your own yelp account keys. (this is pieced together from many sources- thanks to all of them).

```
# yelp
consumerKey = "xxxx"
consumerSecret = "xxxx"
token = "xxxx"
token_secret = "xxxx"

require(httr)
require(httpuv)
require(jsonlite)
# authorization
myapp = oauth_app("YELP", key=consumerKey, secret=consumerSecret)
sig=sign_oauth1.0(myapp, token=token,token_secret=token_secret)

limit <- 10

# 10 bars in Chicago
yelpurl <- paste0("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?limit=",limit,"&location=Chicago%20IL&term=bar")
# or 10 bars by geo-coordinates
yelpurl <- paste0("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?limit=",limit,"&ll=37.788022,-122.399797&term=bar")

locationdata=GET(yelpurl, sig)
locationdataContent = content(locationdata)
locationdataList=jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(locationdataContent))
head(data.frame(locationdataList))
```

Comment: amunategui -- how would you export the data to a text file?

Comment: yelpResults = tryCatch({
    data.frame(locationdataList)
}, error = function(e) { 
    NULL
})

if (!is.null(yelpResults)) {
    set1 <- data.frame("name"=yelpResults$businesses.name,
    'rating'=yelpResults$businesses.rating) }; write.csv(set1,'yelpdata.csv')

Comment: try the above code.Use a tryCatch to make sure you got data. In the above example I pulled only businesses.name and rating.

Comment: Looks like there might be a syntax error -- Error: unexpected 'if' in "yelpResults = tryCatch({ data.frame(locationdataList) }, error = function(e) { NULL }) if"

Comment: put the if on a new line... i should've preceded that with a semicolon, but new line will work...

Comment: Ah -- that works.  However the data frame "yelpResults" is exactly what I would like to export as is.  Apologies in advance but I'm a bit confused about how to simply export the "yelpResults" data frame is this example.

Comment: Looks like some kind of issue with a few nested fields in the JSON output.

Comment: This may be more than you're looking for, but its a full walkthrough off of Yelp: http://amunategui.github.io/yelp-cross-country-trip/

Comment: how can I get a data frame with the 32 variables from the locationdataList?

Comment: @amunategui I find that searches involving special characters are problematic. For instance `a&w restaurants` returns an error. Is there a central location where you can see how to successfully code these characters? The Yelp API Console is no help.